# CSS animate Element when scroll

Tags: html, css, animate.css

i'm looking for a method to animate an element in a div.

```
<div id="outer" style="overflow: hidden;">
<div id="element"><img src="images/bird.png" /></div>
</div>
```

the "element" should come from top and enter the "outer" by scrolling down. when i scroll up the "element" should go out the "outer".

the "element" should fly in and fly out by scrolling in the respective direction.

does anyone have a hint for me how i can do that only with css and without jquery?

Comment: i dont think that it is possible to animate on scroll without javascript

Comment: you can do it using css keyframes, but it isnt fully clear what you want to do,   http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: i want to let fly in a falcon from the top/hidden area of the "outer" when scrolling to the "outer". i thought a bit of a parallax effect to solve it.

Comment: CSS cannot detect positions or scrolling..it styles elements that are on the page. Javascript IS required, Jquery or not.

Comment: ok, thank you for all your anwsers. then i have to switch over to jquery.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
    // apply effects and animations
}
});
```

for more follow
    http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-jquery-scroll-based-animations/

Comment: You cant do that using only css.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a pen that based on what I think you want. Let me know if I have misunderstood.

I am setting a background-image on a container with a fixed background position. This creates a nice 'elevator' effect.

```
.hidden-element {
  background-image: url('https://stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/960w/994D92A0ED.jpg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: 200px -300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Play around with image sizes and positioning to get something that hides and shows on scroll.

http://codepen.io/alexmccabe/pen/RNgXXY